# Granting SNS invoke access to a lambda function's alias while both SNS and the lambda function are created in seperate stacks using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

My question is pretty much identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337753/aws-cdk-give-permission-to-resources-outside-the-stack). But I'm asking it again because none of the provided answers (including the accepted one) work for me.

The scenario is like this. I have 3 stacks.

1. SNS + topic stack
2. Lambda function + alias stack
3. Integration stack (where I connect the lambda function as a subscriber to the SNS topic)

I'm not going to bore you with the details of the first two stacks as they are not important here. But here's the CDK code for the last stack:

```js
const topicArn = `arn:aws:sns:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${topic_name}`;
const snsTopic = Topic.fromTopicArn(stack, `${props.name}Topic`, topicArn);

const lambdaArn = `arn:aws:lambda:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:function:${lambda.name}`;

const version = Version.fromVersionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    lambda: Function.fromFunctionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
        functionArn: lambdaArn,
        role: Role.fromRoleArn( stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}-role-${stack.region}`, props.roleArn),
    }),
    version: `some-alias`,
});

snsTopic.addSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(version, {
    filterPolicy: {/*some filter policy*/},
}));

version.grantInvoke(new ArnPrincipal(topicArn));
```

Before we continue, I understand that I'm using `Version.fromVersionAttributes` while providing the "alias" instead of the version number. Thank god this works cause if it didn't, I could not accomplish what I set out to do. You see, the method `Alias.fromAliasAttributes` expects a "Version" object to return the alias. But I don't have the version number to return the lambda function's Version object. At least, using the `Version.fromVersionAttributes` I can get the alias if I provide the alias string instead of the version number!

Anyways, the snippet code above loads the lambda function's alias into the `version` object and the SNS' topic into `snsTopic`. Then it does two things. First, it subscribes the lambda function's alias to the topic. And secondly, it grants SNS to invoke the lambda function.

This is all good on paper but it does not work. It throws the following exeption when I try to synthesize the CDK code:

```
Error: Cannot modify permission to lambda function. Function is either imported or $LATEST version.
If the function is imported from the same account use `fromFunctionAttributes()` API with the `sameEnvironment` flag.
If the function is imported from a different account and already has the correct permissions use `fromFunctionAttributes()` API with the `skipPermissions` flag.
    at Object.addToResourcePolicy (/home/.../node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/function-base.ts:522:19)
    at Function.addToPrincipalOrResource (/home/.../node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/grant.ts:143:45)
    at Import.grant (/home/.../node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/function-base.ts:504:29)
    at Import.grantInvoke (/home/.../node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/function-base.ts:422:20)
```

Which is thrown by the `grantInvoke` method. So, I tried another approach:

```js
const topicArn = `arn:aws:sns:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${topic_name}`;
const snsTopic = Topic.fromTopicArn(stack, `${props.name}Topic`, topicArn);

const lambdaArn = `arn:aws:lambda:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:function:${lambda.name}`;

const version = Version.fromVersionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    lambda: Function.fromFunctionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
        functionArn: lambdaArn,
        role: Role.fromRoleArn( stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}-role-${stack.region}`, props.roleArn),
    }),
    version: `some-alias`,
});

snsTopic.addSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(version, {
    filterPolicy: {/*some filter policy*/},
}));

version.addPermission(`SNS-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    scope: stack,
    principal: new ServicePrincipal("sns.amazonaws.com"),
    sourceArn: topicArn,
    action: "lambda.InvokeFunction",
});
```

Which is pretty much like the one from before but instead of `grantInvoke`, it's using the `addPermission` method. This time, it does not throw any exception. But at the same time, the generated template has no notion of the add permission in it. And it does not grant SNS the permission to call the lambda function. Basically, it does nothing.

One last note, if I don't try to grant invoke permission to the SNS, the generated template works just fine. It integrates the lambda function's alias as a subscriber to the SNS topic. It's just that when I try and publish a message to the SNS topic since it does not have the permission to invoke the lambda function's alias, it will error out which I can see in the CloudWatch logs. But at least the CDK code and CloudFormation are happy (not that I care about their feelings).

Does anyone know how to make this work?

**[UPDATE]**

One more clarification. If I forget about the part of the code that grants SNS the permission to invoke the lambda function and deploy the stack, I'll end up with an SNS topic, a lambda function, and an alias. The alias is properly subscribed to the SNS topic but as I mentioned before since the SNS is not granted permission to invoke the lambda function's alias, if I publish a message, it will fail. But if I manually grant the invoke permission to the SNS using the AWS console, everything will work as I wanted them to do. So basically, I know what I'm trying to do is doable the only question is how to do it using CDK.

**[UPDATE]**

In the spirit of covering all the potential solutions, I have also tested these two attributes (mentioned in the thrown error message).

```js
const version = Version.fromVersionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    lambda: Function.fromFunctionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
        functionArn: lambdaArn,
        role: Role.fromRoleArn( stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}-role-${stack.region}`, props.roleArn),
        skipPermissions: true,
    }),
    version: `some-alias`,
});
```

and

```js
const version = Version.fromVersionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    lambda: Function.fromFunctionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
        functionArn: lambdaArn,
        role: Role.fromRoleArn( stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}-role-${stack.region}`, props.roleArn),
        sameEnvironment: true,
    }),
    version: `some-alias`,
});
```

But both will throw the same exact exception as before.

**[UPDATE]**

As properly pointed out to me, I didn't mention the CDK version I'm using. So here they are.

```
$ npm run cdk -- --version
2.21.1 (build a6ee543)
```

But the libraries that I use are of a different version. From my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-applicationautoscaling": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-kms": "^1.129.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.129.0",
```

Comment: Have you tried granting the invoke on the lambda, not on the version!? Because at the end of the day the lambda has the policy of who is allowed to invoke it, not the version. And maybe the Version does something funky here. Weird that $LATEST shows up in the error message.

Comment: @luk2302 I haven't tried what you are proposing using CDK. But I have tried it manually. By that I mean I granted SNS invoke permission to the lambda function using AWS console (by mistake) and then when I tried to publish a message to the SNS, it complained that it does not have access to the alias. So in a way, I'm sure what you are proposing will not work. The permission needs to be given to the specific alias.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about the fact that the permission will probably be wrong, just wondering if the CDK would no longer complain.

Comment: Does the SNS subscription point to the alias to the temporarily resolved function version pointed to by the alias?

Comment: @luk2302 I updated my post with some clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a shortcoming (I'm not sure if it's a bug or not) of CDK. It's been discussed [there](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7588).

The solution is to use the lower-level CloudFormation APIs. Like this:

```js
const topicArn = `arn:aws:sns:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${topic_name}`;
const snsTopic = Topic.fromTopicArn(stack, `${props.name}Topic`, topicArn);

const lambdaArn = `arn:aws:lambda:${stack.region}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:function:${lambda.name}`;

const version = Version.fromVersionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    lambda: Function.fromFunctionAttributes(stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
        functionArn: lambdaArn,
        role: Role.fromRoleArn( stack, `sns-${props.name}-${lambda.name}-role-${stack.region}`, props.roleArn),
        sameEnvironment: true,
    }),
    version: `some-alias`,
});

snsTopic.addSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(version, {
    filterPolicy: {/*some filter policy*/},
}));

new CfnPermission(stack, `SNS-${props.name}-${lambda.name}`, {
    action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    principal: "sns.amazonaws.com",
    functionName: `${lambdaArn}:${props.tenant}-${props.env}`,
    sourceArn: topicArn,
});
```

Comment: The linked issue has been fixed, though.

Comment: @gshpychka Maybe I'm using an older version of CDK but it is not fixed for me.

Comment: It will be helpful if you specify the version of CDK you're using.